# tkinter toggle buttons, only one can be pressed at a time

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make toggle buttons via tkinter that can be pressed only one at a time. And I need to save buttons on and off time.

It's working as it should, but whenever any button is toggled and I'm clicking on another button, happens weird stuff like the button not toggling properly, or another button being toggled.

```py
from datetime import *
from tkinter import *

def record():

    is_on = False
    but_list = []

    def record_time(name, bt):
        nonlocal is_on, but_list

        but_list.append(name)
        if is_on:
            is_on = False
            time_off = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
            bt.config(bg='#F0F0F0')
            but_list.append(time_off)
            print(is_on, time_off)
        else:
            is_on = True
            time_on = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
            bt.config(bg='green')
            but_list.append(time_on)
            print(is_on, time_on)

        return but_list, is_on

    recwin = Tk()

    for c in range(3): recwin.columnconfigure(index=c)
    for r in range(3): recwin.rowconfigure(index=r)

    bt1 = Button(recwin, text='training', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time('training', bt1))
    bt1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=15)
    bt1_2 = Button(recwin, text='event', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time('event', bt1_2))
    bt1_2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=15)
    bt1_3 = Button(recwin, text='other', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time('other', bt1_3))
    bt1_3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=15)

record()
```

I am very new to programming, so I am really can't figure out what I need to do to this code

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. What do you need `but_list` to contain? The activity (training, event, other) followed by the time the button was on? Why do you need to remember the off time then?

Comment: I posted an answer based on what I understood, tell me if you need it edited.

Comment: "weird stuff" isn't a useful description. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want `but_list` to contain the activity (training, event, other) followed by the time the activity button was on. In case no button was pressed, I think you want to know the time spent without activity.

To achieve this, you can store the last time a button was pressed using [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time), and do a subtraction to get the time interval in seconds (then maybe use the `datetime` module to format it).

You can store the `Button` objects in a list, to unselect all of them except the clicked button each time you click one. This will also make the code easier to understand, simplifying the `lambda` functions.

To know if a button is on or off, you can store the on/off colors in a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) and check if the button color is the "on" color.

To set the `but_list` value (which I will call `state` because of the way I understood your question), you can use a variable called `next_activity`, which you will have defined the previous time the user pressed a button: this is because when you press for example the "Training" button, you only want to know your time spent training **the next time** you press a button, for example "Other". And you only want this time displayed after that, and so on.

Here is a MRE illustrating this:

```py
from time import time
from tkinter import *

def record():

    is_on = False # is a button pressed?
    buttons = [] # contains all Button objects
    last_pressed_time = time() # for calculating durations
    next_activity = 'nothing' # activity to put in state next time
    state = [] # contains the type of activity + the time on/off
    colors = {'off': '#F0F0F0', 'on': 'green'} # button colors

    def record_time(id):
        nonlocal is_on, state, last_pressed_time, next_activity

        current_btn = buttons[id] # button pressed last

        state = [next_activity, time()-last_pressed_time]

        if current_btn['bg'] == colors['on']: # button turned off
            current_btn['bg'] = colors['off']
            is_on = False
            next_activity = 'nothing'

        else: # button turned on
            current_btn['bg'] = colors['on']
            is_on = True
            next_activity = current_btn['text']

        # release all other buttons
        for button in buttons:
            if button != current_btn:
                button['bg'] = colors['off']

        # prepare for next time
        last_pressed_time = time()
        print(state)

    recwin = Tk()

    for c in range(3): recwin.columnconfigure(index=c)
    for r in range(3): recwin.rowconfigure(index=r)

    buttons.append(Button(recwin, text='training', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time(0)))
    buttons.append(Button(recwin, text='event', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time(1)))
    buttons.append(Button(recwin, text='other', width=15, height=2, command=lambda: record_time(2)))
    for c in range(3):
        buttons[c].grid(row=2, column=c, padx=10, pady=15)

    recwin.mainloop()

record()
```

I added `recwin.mainloop()` in the `record` function to make it easier to use.